# How to allow zooming in and out of iframe in google chrome through touch screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

How to allow zooming in and out of iframe in google chrome through touch screen .

When i tried to zoom the content of the iframe in my galaxy tab it fails !

---

```
<iframe id="rad_pdf" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="930px" frameborder="0" style="border:0px none #ffffff;" src="RadPdf.axd?rt=2&dk=0000046432rO0XVW8JS3SBUMM5AE2XKXB&cn=rad_pdf&un=rad_pdf">
```

Comment: Is it an iFrame with a PDF inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile browsers don't support the rendering of PDF unlike desktop based browsers like Chrome and Firefox, which have in-built rendering features. However, this again performs based on the user's browser settings.

If you're're looking to render PDF on mobile browsers, have a look at this JavaScript framework called [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). You can try the demo here http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html and check how it functions on mobile/tablet browsers.

You can use it according to your needs. Hope this is useful.